# Using compressorjs with React Native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to using the amazing [compressorjs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/compressorjs/) library in my React native expo project.

Currently, I have this:

```js
import Compressor from 'compressorjs';

export const uploadPicture = async (uri, path) => {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
        };
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });

    new Compressor(blob, { //<--- Problem
        quality: 0.6,
        maxWidth: 512,
        maxHeight: 512,
        success(result) {
            console.log(result)
        },
        error(err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    })

    blob.close();

    //firebase stuff to upload after...
}
```

I'm assuming this doesn't work because `compressorjs` only allows `File` and `Blob` types and I'm inserting a `Promise` instead. But I have no clue what to do instead.

If anyone can point me into the right direction, that would be amazing!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API [`response.blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) method to get the image blob from the URI as opposed to using [Ajax XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Like this -

###### Getting the blob via the URI

```js
let blob = await fetch(uri).then(r => r.blob());
```

You can also take it a step further by getting the actual file from the blob, like this:

##### Getting the image file from the blob

```js
let file = await fetch(url)
  .then((r) => r.blob())
  .then((blobFile) => new File([blobFile], "fileName", { type: "image/png" }));
```

##### Your finished code should look something like:

```js
import Compressor from "compressorjs";

export const uploadPicture = async (uri, path) => {
  let blob = await fetch(uri).then(r => r.blob());

  new Compressor(blob, {
    ...
  });
};
```

##### OR this

```js
import Compressor from "compressorjs";

export const uploadPicture = async (uri, path) => {
  let file = await fetch(url)
    .then((r) => r.blob())
    .then((blobFile) =>
       new File(
         [blobFile],
         "fileName",
         { type: "image/png" })
     );

  new Compressor(file, {
    ...
  });
};
```

##### Disclaimer

Please note that there's no guarantee that this suggestion will definitely solve your problem but it's DEFINITELY worth a shot.

Cheers.

Comment: Issue sadly remains. I'm afraid maybe the library is just not compatible on React native. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You must be getting an error message. What is the error message? @YourivdHeuvel

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but compressorjs will not work with React native.
However, since you're using Expo I advise you to use [image manipulator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/).

```js
const manipResult = await manipulateAsync(
  mediaURI, 
  [{ resize: { width: 800, height: 600 } }], 
  {
    compress: 1, // you can also compress here
    format: SaveFormat.JPEG, // and pick you preferred format
  }
);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35515075)